# There is no display of code for my program?

Tags: java

i'm not getting output for my java program?

```
package live;

public class ACTIVE
{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        for(int i =0;i<0;i++)
        {
            if (i%2==0) {
                continue;
            }
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

the output must be :
1
3
5
7
9

Comment: Your for loop runs while the condition `i<0` is true, but as you initially set `i` to `0` it never is  - so the loop never runs.  Try `i<10`.

Comment: `int i =0;i<0;` will make it not executed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (i%2 == 0) {
            continue;
        }
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

And the output is:

```
1
3
5
7
9
```

Answer (score 0):

You set i to 0 and your for loop only runs if i<0, so change it to 10 and it should work.

```
public static void main(String args[])
    {
         for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
         {
           if(i%2==0)
               continue;
           System.out.println(i);
          }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

It might help to specify exactly what the parts of a for loop are:

> for(**initialization**; **termination**; **increment**)

- The **initialization** expression sets up the initial conditions for the for loop.
- The loop will stop when the **termination** expression evaluates to `false`.
- The **increment** expression will execute once for every iteration of your loop.

So with that in mind, let's look at what your loop is actually doing:

```
for(int i = 1; i < 0; i++)
```

So your loop **initializes** by creating a variable named `i` and setting it to `1`.  Next, your loop says to **terminate** when `i < 0` is `false`.  But you just set `i` to be equal to `1`, which is not less than zero!  Therefore your termination condition is already false *before you even start iterating through your loop*, meaning that the loop never runs at all.

Based on your expected output, it seems like what you intended to write was:

```
for(int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
```

Notice that this will now terminate when `i` is greater or equal to `10`.

---

Also, I'd recommend against this code for a couple of reasons:

```
if(i%2==0)
    continue;
System.out.println(i);
```

It's generally bad practice to have if statements without using braces to delineate the code to be executed inside the if.  Also, your logic is kind of "reversed", for lack of a better way of phrasing it.  It would be (arguably) more intuitive to write:

```
if(i % 2 != 0) {
  System.out.println(i);
}
```

That removes the need to `continue`, and slightly improves readability.

Answer (score 0):

This code will not work because of loop condition fails

```
 for(int i =0;i<0;i++)
```

or may be you forget to update condition to

```
 for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
```

try this

```
package live;

 public class ACTIVE {

  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        if(i%2==0)
            continue;

        System.out.println(i);
    }
  }

}
```

try this working fiddle
 http://tpcg.io/KGl2Wr

Answer (score 0):

> i'm not getting output for my java program?

That is because your for-loop fails the given condition to run.

```
for(int i=0;i<0;i++)
//1) Initialize i as 0
//2) if i<0 is true, run statments within for-loop
```

At (2), the condition is false since 0 is not less than 0, hence your loop won't run. Try anything more than 0 for your loop to run ( e.g. `i<1` )

Also, your continue statement can be avoided by doing:

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    if(i%2 != 0)
        System.out.println(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me keep it simple as possible without going deep into terminologies.
Let's take an example Ok?
Suppose I give you 10 bucks and I ask you to go and spend but you are allowed to spend only 0 bucks? Will you be able to spend any money? The answer is no right. Why is it so? It is because the condition doesn't match only, you won't be able to perform the task(here expenditure of money) right. 
Similarly, in your loop, you have coded that :

```
for(int i=0;i<0;i++)
```

Now tell me look at this part of your code:

> **i=0** and **i<0**

Did you see what did you do wrong? You have told the program ok, I am setting the value of i to 0, you will have to run the loop till the part where i remains less than 0. But i can never be less than 0 because 0 is not less than 0. So your condition isn't satisfied at all and is not executed at all.
So what you need to do is set the condition as **i<10** and your loop will work.
However, note that your loop can be made more effecient.
Hope it helps :D